# Update a column in table with information from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

Im already have this:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012];
--- somewhere create table  
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[PersonPhone]','U') IS NOT NULL   
DROP TABLE [dbo].[PersonPhone]  
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonPhone](  
    [BusinessEntityID] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [PhoneNumber] nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,  
    [PhoneNumberTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,  
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL)  
--- and append new column  
ALTER Table [dbo].[PersonPhone]  
ADD [StartDate] date NULL  
--- after this, i want copy dates in this column (at another table, we increase dates by one)  
UPDATE [dbo].[PersonPhone]
SET [StartDate] = [NewTable].[NewDate]
FROM (
       SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, [HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory].[StartDate]) AS [NewDate],
          row_number() over(order by (select 1)) AS [RN]
   FROM [HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory]
 ) [NewTable]
```

How to improve query to copy the values ​​from [NewTable] to [dbo].[PersonPhone].[StartDate] row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your Update:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[PersonPhone]
SET [StartDate] = DATEADD(day, 1, [HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory].[StartDate])
FROM [HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory]
GO

SELECT row_number() over(order by (select 1)) AS [RN] FROM [HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory]
```

Comment: SQL Server told me that "This query returned more then one result..."

Comment: Now write, that "Cant call methods for datetime"

Comment: Already copy, but all rows have one value. How to copy row by rows?

Comment: if that's the case, and if i were you, i'd put the update query into a looping statement.